# How to generate answer from list of questions using nlp?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nlp, nltk

I have a list named as questions:

```
>>> questions=['Where do you live?', 'What is my favourite color?', 'What is your age', 'Do you like coding?']
```

and a list named as answer:

```
>>> answers=['I live in India','my favourite color is orange', 'my age is 16','I love coding']
```

What I need to do is make a function which takes a string as a different question and returns the appropriate answer. For example :

```
>>> def get_answer(question):
      ... # Compare the string with the questions list and then give the appropriate answer accordingly
>>> ans=get_answer('Do you live in india or america?')
>>> print(ans)
I live in India
```

What I have tried so far

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords 
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

def simi(X,Y):   
    # tokenization 
    X_list = word_tokenize(X)  
    Y_list = word_tokenize(Y) 
  
    # sw contains the list of stopwords 
    sw = stopwords.words('english')  
    l1 =[];l2 =[] 
  
    # remove stop words from the string 
    X_set = {w for w in X_list if not w in sw}  
    Y_set = {w for w in Y_list if not w in sw} 
  
    # form a set containing keywords of both strings  
    rvector = X_set.union(Y_set)  
    for w in rvector: 
        if w in X_set: l1.append(1) # create a vector 
        else: l1.append(0) 
        if w in Y_set: l2.append(1) 
        else: l2.append(0) 
    c = 0
  
    # cosine formula  
    for i in range(len(rvector)): 
        c+= l1[i]*l2[i] 
    cosine = c / float((sum(l1)*sum(l2))**0.5) 
    return cosine

questions=['Where do you live?', 'What is my favourite color?', 'What is your age', 'Do you like coding?']
answers=['I live in India','my favourite color is orange', 'my age is 16','I love coding']

ques='Do you live in india or america?'

lst=[simi(ques,char) for char in questions]

print(answers[lst.index(max(lst))])
```

Comment: I tried the cosine similarity and removing stopwords but this process for each iteration makes it slow and not very effective

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dictionary mapping the keywords to their answers.

```py
questions=['Where do you live?', 'What is my favourite color?', 'What is your age', 'Do you like coding?']
answers=['I live in India','my favourite color is orange', 'my age is 16','I love coding']
keywords = ['live', 'color', 'age', 'coding']

mapper = {key:value for key,value in zip(keywords, answers)}
def get_answer(question):
    words = question.split(' ')
    for word in words:
        if word in keywords:
            break
    return mapper[word]

ans=get_answer('Do you live in india or america?')
print(ans) # prints "I live in India"
```

You could expand your dictionary(`mapper`) to include more words using NLP.

Comment: Thanks but how to extract keywords and append to kewords list

Comment: @YashMakan, `set(keywords).intersection(w.strip(" .,?!'\"") for w in question.split())`. Alternatively you can pass [`string.punctuation`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.punctuation) to `str.strip()`.